# anchor element is not clickable in Rainbow Wheel

Tags: html, css

anchor element is not clickable in Rainbow Wheel
I have been working on creating a rainbow wheel that has 14 different colors. I have applied transforms and rotate to make it working but issue is that the anchor elemnets are not clickable as i did rotation to the element. Any possible suggestion.
Here is link to the [code pen](https://codepen.io/Saghir/pen/eYmzxVv)

and my code is:

```css
 /*WRAPPER*/
    #wrapper{ 
     margin: 40px auto 0; 
     width:266px; 
     position:relative;
    }
    
    #txt{
     color:#eaeaea; 
    }
    
    
    /*WHEEL*/
    #wheel{
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
     border-radius:50%; 
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     
     transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    #inner-wheel{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     
     -webkit-transition: all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
     -moz-transition:    all 6 cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
     -o-transition:      all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
     -ms-transition:     all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99);
     transition:         all 6s cubic-bezier(0,.99,.44,.99); 
    }
    
    #wheel div.sec{
     position: absolute;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-style: solid;
     /*border-width: 260px 150px 0px;*/
      border-top-width: 260px;
      border-right-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width: 150px;
     border-color: #19c ;
     transform-origin: 150px 258px;
     left:100px;
     top:-4px; 
     opacity:1;
    }
    
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(1){
     transform: rotate(25.7deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(25.7deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(25.7deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(25.7deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(25.7deg);
     border-color: #CE9020 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(2){
     transform: rotate(51.4deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(51.4deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(51.4deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(51.4deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(51.4deg);
     border-color: #C14825 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(3){
     transform: rotate(77.1deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(77.1deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(77.1deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(77.1deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(77.1deg);
     border-color: #CC233A transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(4){
     transform: rotate(102.8deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(102.8deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(102.8deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(102.8deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(102.8deg);
     border-color: #C01E60 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(5){
     transform: rotate(128.5deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(128.5deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(128.5deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(128.5deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(128.5deg);
     border-color: #852780 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(6){
     transform: rotate(154.2deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(154.2deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(154.2deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(154.2deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(154.2deg);
     border-color: #5C2C8C transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(7){
     transform: rotate(179.9deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(179.9deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(179.9deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(179.9deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(179.9deg);
     border-color: #2E308C transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(8){
     transform: rotate(205.6deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(205.6deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(205.6deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(205.6deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(205.6deg);
     border-color: #034D9D transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(9){
     transform: rotate(231.3deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(231.3deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(231.3deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(231.3deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(231.3deg);
     border-color: #0089CB transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(10){
     transform: rotate(257deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(257deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(257deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(257deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(257deg);
     border-color: #00ABC2 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(11){
     transform: rotate(282.7deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(282.7deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(282.7deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(282.7deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(282.7deg);
     border-color: #00A088 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(12){
     transform: rotate(308.4deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(308.4deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(308.4deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(308.4deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(308.4deg);
     border-color: #009556 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(13){
     transform: rotate(334.1deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(334.1deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(334.1deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(334.1deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(334.1deg);
     border-color: #55AE46 transparent; 
    }
    #wheel div.sec:nth-child(14){
     transform: rotate(359deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(359.8deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(359.8deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(359.8deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(359.8deg);
     border-color: #A6AC35 transparent; 
    }
    
    
    #wheel div.sec .fa{
     margin-top: -200px;
     margin-left:-100px;
      color: #F2F0F0;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10000000;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:18px;
     transform:rotate(-105deg);
     text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px;
    }
    
    #wheel div.sec .fainv{
     margin-top: -200px;
     margin-left:-100px;
      color: #F2F0F0;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10000000;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:18px;
     transform:rotate(75deg);
     text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px -1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 0px
    }
    
    #center{
     width:68px;
     height:68px;
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-34px 0 0 -34px;
     border-radius:50%;
     z-index:1000;
     background:#fff;
     font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
      
      -webkit-user-select: none; 
      -moz-user-select: none;    
      -ms-user-select: none;     
      -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;   
    }
    #inner-center{
     width:54px;
     height:54px;
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-27px 0 0 -27px;
     border-radius:50%;
     
     z-index:999;
     
     background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
     
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="wheel">
        <div id="inner-wheel">
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fa">Sales</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fa">Operations</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fa"> Managers</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fa">IT</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="fa">Digi Market</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="https://www.bing.com"><span class="fa">Mark</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fa">E-Com</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">Prod</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">Merchandis</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">CS</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">AR</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">HR</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">RR</span></a></div>
          <div class="sec"><a href="#"><span class="fainv">AP</span></a></div>
                
        </div>
        <div id="center">
           <div id="inner-center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following workaround:

```
#wheel div.sec {
   pointer-events: none;
}

#wheel div.sec .fa,
#wheel div.sec .fainv {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

This adds the pointer events only to the elements where they make sense.